# the file size keeps on increasing

Tags: java

On executing the below code the size of "username.txt" file on device keeps on increasing. What is the reason?

```
package files2;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.PrintStream;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class extractor {
public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner fromFile=new Scanner(new File("emails.txt"));
    PrintStream toFile=new PrintStream("username.txt");
    char symbol;
    while(fromFile.hasNext()) {
        symbol=fromFile.findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0);
        while(symbol !='@') {
            toFile.print(symbol);
            symbol=fromFile.findWithinHorizon(".",0).charAt(0);
        }
        fromFile.nextLine();
        toFile.println();
    }
    fromFile.close();
    toFile.close();

}

}
```

Comment: The reason is that you are writing into that file. What do you expect?

Comment: The reason is infinte loop

Comment: well, you keep writing to it. Files increase if you write into them, it's pretty normal.

Comment: @VidorVistrom don't while(fromFile.hasNext()) return flase after it reaches to the end of the file?

Comment: `findWithinHorizon(".",0)` will look for any character - if you want to look for a dot, you need to escape it: `findWithinHorizon("\\.",0).`

Comment: @assylias and thats what I meant